# choose the item of a select

Tags: php, javascript, html

I need to select a specific item of a combobox in my page when i click in a button.
I am using php and javascript code in my page.

Actually i am calling a javascript function at the "onclick" of the button. But i still dont get the right command to do this.

example:

```
<select id="TEST">
<option> a</option>
<option> b</option>
<option> c</option>
</select>
```

i want to show the item b when i click in the button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<select id="select1">
    ...
</select>
<button onclick="chooseItem('select1', 1)">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function chooseItem(id, index){
        var selectElement = document.getElementById(id);
        selectElement.selectedIndex = index;
    }
</script>
```

or with jQuery:

```
<select id="select1">
    ...
</select>
<button id="button1">
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#button1").click(function(e){
           $("#select1").each(function(){
               this.selectedIndex = 1;
           });
       });
   });
```

});

Comment: This is more for Paulo; if you haven't checked out jQuery, you really need to. It can help you with things such as this and simplify your Javascript drastically: http://jquery.com/

Comment: Personally, I think the jQuery solutions is more complicated for this particular case. However, if you are dealing with multiple items, you can write it very concisely with jQuery.

Comment: The non-jQuery solution is superior in almost every conceivable way, although I'd have the `<script>` element before the button to guarantee the function is available when the user clicks the button.

Comment: Tim, that's an excellent point - ideally the `<script>` should be before the button. That said, in my real-world pages I prefer to do all the plumbing after the page has loaded, and I choose whatever method is considered proper for whatever js framework is used.

Answer (score 1):

use selectedIndex property.